# Create materialized view in Clickhouse times out

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to create a large, populated materialized view in Clickhouse db, but it times out while creating. The error is:

```
Code: 159, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Timeout exceeded: elapsed 122.162157893 seconds, maximum: 120 (version 20.4.3.16 (official build)) (version 20.4.3.16 (official build))
```

To fix this I'd like to increase this timeout but the problem is, I don't know which one it is. There is no timeout setting in my driver properties that has this value of 120s.
I have set the socket_timeout already to 500s.

How do I increase the timeout that triggers the above error after 120s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like triggered <strike>lock_acquire_timeout</strike> [max_execution_time](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/query-complexity/#max-execution-time).

Try to either:

- don't define POPULATE-clause and populate materialized view *manually* by chunks

```sql
# define MV without POPULATE

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS mv_name ..
ENGINE = engine
AS SELECT ..
FROM ..;


# manually populate it by call of several INSERTs

INSERT INTO mv_name
SELECT ..
FROM ..
WHERE dt_column >= '..' AND dt_column < ''; // <-- restrict the chunk size
```

- or increase the <strike>*lock_acquire_timeout*</strike> *max_execution_time*-value

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS mv_name ..
ENGINE = engine
AS SELECT ..
FROM ..
SETTINGS max_execution_time = 600;
```

---

To define the settings that set to 120 use query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM system.settings
WHERE value = '120'
```

Comment: The SELECT * FROM system.settings was really helpful! It turned out that I had to increase the setting max_execution_time.

Comment: No, it's the receive_timeout.   lock_acquire_timeout -- produces deadlock timeout message.